# Sort list according to elements in sublist

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a simple list composed of several sublists like so:

```
a = [[4, 3, 2, 1], [5, 8, 7, 6], [12, 11, 10, 9]]
```

I need to sort this according to the elements in the sublist `a[1]` in descending order so it will like like this:

```
sorted_a = [(3, 2, 1, 4), (8, 7, 6, 5), (11, 10, 9, 12)]
```

I've tried using sorted:

```
sorted_a = sorted(a, key=lambda x: -x[2])
```

but it returns:

```
[[12, 11, 10, 9], [5, 8, 7, 6], [4, 3, 2, 1]]
```

which is not what I need at all.

Comment: Is it `a[1]` or `a[2]`?

Comment: I'm sorting all the sublists rearranging `a[1]` in descending order.

Comment: but you are also sorting a[0] and a[2] in ascending order ?

Comment: I need to sort all the sublists following the sorting done in sublist `a[1]`. So if the elements in this sublist are arranged in a given way, the elements in all the other sublists should be re-arranged too in the same way. I'm sorry if I explained myself poorly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you actually want to sort the sublists?

```
zip(*sorted(zip(*a), key=lambda x: -x[1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhapse this is what you're looking for:

```
a = [[4, 3, 2, 1], [5, 6, 7, 8], [12, 11, 10, 9]]
[sorted(list) for list in a]
```

Returns: `[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]`

Or, if you additionally want to sort by the first element:

```
a = [[4, 3, 2, 1], [12, 11, 10, 9], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
sorted([sorted(list) for list in a], key=min)
```

Also returns: `[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]`

Answer (score 0):

This sounds confusing ;-)  From the comments, it sure sounds like you want to take the permutation that would reverse-sort a[1], and apply that permutation to all sublists.  Well, any 1-liner for that would be insanely obscure.  So here's a straightforward way to do that:

```
a = [[4,3,2,1], [5,6,7,8], [12,11,10,9]]
# compute the permutation needed to reverse-sort a[1]
decorated = [(v, i) for i, v in enumerate(a[1])]
decorated.sort(reverse=True)
perm = [i for v, i in decorated]
for sublist in a:
    sublist[:] = [sublist[i] for i in perm]
print a
```

Comment: I apologize for the confusing question, I try to strip things down to the fundamentals and sometimes I overdo it. It may seem like I want to revert because I happened to write the sublist `a[1]` in ascending order but it's not really what I need. I'll try to make this more clear in the question.